# Zend Framework Mail: Base64 header encoding on incoming mails

Tags: zend-framework, header, base64, imap, pop3

I try to download emails from my POP3/IMAP accounts using Zend Framework 1.12 and it's working fine. QP header fields will be decoded automatically. However, when a header field (from name or subject) is base64 encoded like this:

```
=?UTF-8?B?c3DEvsWIYcWl?=
```

it will not automatically base64 decode it. Don't know why. While it would be easy to fix this "my way", I would like to do it right.

Can anybody recommend a good approach how to deal with base64 headers?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use [iconv_mime_decode_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode-headers.php) PHP function.

```
   $decoded = iconv_mime_decode_headers('Subject: '.$subject, 0, "UTF-8");
   var_dump(decoded['Subject']);
```

Note, that you can pass multiple header parameters to one function, by separating them with newline or "\n". e.g.

```
   $headers = "Subject: {$subject}\nFrom: {$from}";
   $decoded = iconv_mime_decode_headers($headers, 0, "UTF-8");
```

In this case you will get array with keys "Subject" and "From" with decoded data.

Answer (score 0):

Its the responsibility of `mail mime parsers` to decode the mail headers. There are open source `base64 decoders` available on net which can be used to decode these strings.